# How to nest navigators with wrapping Views in React native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to have a nested view between my DrawerNavigator and my TabNavigator but I cannot get it to work.

Code:

```
const SubNavigation = TabNavigator({
  SubOne: { screen: SubOne },
  SubTwo: { screen: SubTwo },
}, {
  tabBarComponent: TabBarTop,
  tabBarPosition: 'top',
  initialRouteName: 'SubOne',
});

class SubScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Subscreen',
  };

  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
      <View>
        <Header navigation={navigation} />
        <SubNavigation navigation={navigation} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const PrimaryNav = DrawerNavigator({
  StartScreen: { screen: StartScreen },
  SubScreen: { screen: SubScreen },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'StartScreen',
});
```

I do it like this because I want a custom header for each PrimaryNav screen. I don't really know if this is best practice, I am used to use react-router where you can define container components similar to this.

I get the error `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` with the code above.

Comment: From the error log, can you see if the exception is coming from react-navigation callstack or from your own code? It would be helpful to post out the error screen.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, using redux, react-native, and react-navigation.

After debugging react-navigation `TabRouter` inside the `TabNavigator`, the issue comes down to [this line of code](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/src/routers/TabRouter.js#L44)

Due to wrapping a `StackNavigator`/`TabNavigator` (aka a `NavigationContainer`) component deep in your hierarchy, the routing doesn't properly get wired up...unless you need to give it a little extra help.

In the wrapper component that's referenced as a `screen` by the higher up Stack/TabNavigator's RouteConfig, you need to supply a reference to the router in the `NavigationContainer` you're wrapping. This is way more complicated to explain in english than in code, so here's an example of how I roughly got my navigation working with wrappers.

```js
//Landing.js - the top most component of the app
const LandingNav = StackNavigator(
  {
    LoggedInTabs: {
      screen: LoggedInTabs
    },
    LoggedOut: {
      screen: LoggedOut
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'LoggedInTabs',
  }
})

class Landing extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <LandingNav
      navigation={
        addNavigationHelpers({
          dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
          state: this.props.nav
        })
      }/>
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const nav = state.nav;
  return {
    //...,
    nav
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Landing);



//LoggedInTabs.js

const TabsNav = TabNavigator(
{
  Home: {
    screen: Home
  },
  Notifications: {
    screen: Notifications
  },
  Friends: {
    screen: Friends
  },
  Me: {
    screen: Me
  }
});

export default class LoggedInTabs extends React.Component {

  //THIS property is what I was missing, this is key!!
  static router = TabsNav.router;

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        {
          //...Put in whatever you need to wrap here.
        }
        <TabsNav
          navigation={props.navigation}/>
        {
          // ^ This is also very key for wrapping. This also caused some pain for me earlier.
        }
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```